# EventArc trigger on multiple types

Tags: google-cloud-platform, event-arc

I'm trying to create an eventarc trigger that listens for multiple CloudEvent types. However, all I'm seeing is that at trigger has 1 CloudEvent type but can filter on attributes.

I do control the code for publishing, so I could add logic that clones all published CloudEvents and publishes another CloudEvent with a generic type but that feels pretty dirty and the error paths are brutal.

I could also create a subscriber to the eventarc's channel pubsub but that feels like gcp could change how eventarc is powered at any minute and break my subscriber.